# ¿Cómo restar dos columnas en python?

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy tratando de restar dos columnas en Python, pero no obtengo el resultado deseado.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd 

df0 = pd.read_csv('Archivo.txt')

df0['newcol'] = df0['tt1'] - df0['IMF5']
```

Mi dataframe es:

```
     IMF5   tt1
-2.176930499    10.57
-2.181098719    9.72
-2.183905516    9.17
-2.185325527    10.12
-2.185333389    10.01
-2.183903751    9.9
-2.18101153     9.27
```

Comment: Es un error de tipeo `df` debería ser `df0` (-Vamos hombre que deberías saber que hay que poner en la pregunta qué error da!!)

Comment: @Pollo Okey man :D